# Apple Numbers - How to make sure a cell never goes below Zero

Tags: excel, numbers, apple-numbers

I have created a spreadsheet in apple numbers and third cell is the difference between 1 and 2. How do I make sure the 3rd cell never goes below Zero if the 2nd amount is greater than than the first amount?

£650.00 £100.00 £550.00

Many thanks for assistance

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a formula:

```
=IF(C2>B2,0,(B2−C2))
```

so when the 2nd column is greater it returns 0, otherwise the difference

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this one (simpler)

`=Max(B2-C2, 0)`